# Rad grid form template

Tags: c#, asp.net, telerik-grid

In ***Radgrid*** basing upon dropdown **selected index changed** i am binding the Radgrid. In that i click `edit button Form template is opened` and editing.

The following First image showing suppose i opened any record again in dropdown i am

> selecting another item the formtemplate is still opened.

[image: Image1]

[image: Image2]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the SelectIndexChanged event of the DropDownList, cancel the edit mode of the RadGrid by calling these methods:

```
radGrid1.EditIndexes.Clear(); 
radGrid1.Rebind();
```